# A mi enlace solo se entra con doble click

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo un enlace protegido por autorización que funciona, pero el problema es
que para acceder a la ruta tengo que darle dos veces click:

En este código hago una petición al servidor para que me valide el token y si llega una respuesta que retorne true.

```
isLoggedIn() :boolean {

    var token: string | undefined;
    const body = { token: token = Cookies.get('token') };

    this.http.post<any>(this.API + 'token-validate', body, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(
        (response): string => {
        if (response.body.validation && response.body.role == 'ROLE_ADMIN') { 

          this.response = JSON.stringify(response)
        }
        return  this.response;
      })
      
      if(this.response){
        return true
      }
      return false
    } 

//Si el codigo de arriba esta muy feo es que soy autodidacta no tengo a ningun profesor guiandome.
```

Luego entonces en el guard si **this.permission** da true es que puedo acceder a la ruta.

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    this.permission = this._userService.isLoggedIn();

    console.log(this.permission);

    if (this.permission) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

El problema si os fijais tengo un **console.log(this.permission)** que me revela lo que me esta devolviendo exactamente **isloggedIn().**

Si hago un click a mi enlace la consola me imprime false pero si hago otro click me imprime true.

Esto solamente pasa cuando intento entrar al enlace por primera vez, me gustaria resolver esta molestia de alguna manera y se me ocurre usar async await para que mi código se espere una respuesta del servidor pero no se como implementarlo, tampoco se si esto es una solución y tan si quiera si hay una solución para esto.